# informatica power center. find dependency view in repository metadata

Tags: informatica-powercenter

I have a question about informatica metadata, and i will be glad for any advices.

We can rightclick on any workflow in Informatica power center and choose 
"Dependencies". After it, we see the window, where we can choose, what dependent objects we want to see.

[image]

When we press "OK", appears "VIEW Dependencies" window with list of dependent objects and info about them (object_name, object_type, timestamp, status, etc).
Does anybody know, how to select this list from informatica metadata repository tables? Or may be somebody know the way, how can i extract this select from power center designer.

I know about separeted views with mappings, sources, targets, etc, but may be you know, how to get exactly the same data, as on this window.

Thank you for any help

Answer (score 0):

You need to realize that these data are in many different tables in the repository database, and it will be even more complex if you have versioning turned on in the repository.
We created a query that gives all dependent tables (sources, targets and lookup sources) for a workflow, but that took two of our smartest people more than a week, and still it has several drawbacks in a more generalized setting. One example is that it doesn't support worklets since we don't use it...

Can you narrow down the requirement, then we may be able to point you in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

We can check the dependencies through querying the Informatica repository Metadata tables. But for that we need to know the oracle connection details in which the metadata tables are resided(Mostly Informatica admins knows about the connection). If we get the connection details we can check the below tables:
OPB_MAPPING,
OPB_SUBJECT,
OPB_WIDGET(for transformations),
OPB_TASK,
OPB_WFLOW_RUN etc

Below is the sample SQL query that shows the names of all the Folders in the repository and the mappings contained in them along with last saved date, mapping version number and versioning comments, if any.

```
SELECT
  S.SUBJ_NAME FOLDER,
  M.MAPPING_NAME MAPPING,
  M.VERSION_NUMBER VERSION_NUMBER,
  CASE WHEN M.IS_VALID = 1 THEN 'YES' ELSE 'NO' END IS_VALID,
  M.LAST_SAVED SAVED_ON,
  M.CHECKOUT_USER_ID,
  M.COMMENTS
FROM OPB_MAPPING M, OPB_SUBJECT S
WHERE M.SUBJECT_ID = S.SUBJ_ID
AND is_visible = 1
ORDER BY 1, 2, 3;
```